# How to use the QGIS Linear Referencing Plugin?

Tags: qgis, linear-referencing

I'm having trouble getting the Faunalia Linear Referencing Plugin set up properly in QGIS 1.8.  I've gotten to the point where I can do the Calibration, but I get a few warnings about missing lines, or lines with no start/end points.

Basically I don't understand what is needed to do the calibration properly.  I need more details about what the field schema should be in the input line and point layers.  It is unclear what is meant by "Route must have exactly the same identification for lines and calibration points..."

At this point the calibration "successfully" finishes, but when I use the "Info" tool on line segments all the labels come back as "0.0".

Any insight from your experience much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you try the new plugin in 2.01 Dufour, **[QChainage](https://github.com/mach0/qchainage)**.

Comment: Your answer contained a question so I re-phrased it as a statement.  I hope the link I found and added is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the post [QGIS Linear Referencing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/130331/4972). I've described there the functionality offered by the [plugin LRS](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/lrs/) for Linear Referencing on QGIS.

LRS improves the usability of the former Linear Referencing plugin by Faunalia. It also does not require the layers to be stored in PostGIS, you can use any QGIS layer (i.e., from any source) for linear referencing.