# Linear referencing using QGIS only

Tags: qgis, labeling, linear-referencing

I would like to do some basic linear referencing (label the distance along a line every 1000 m e.g.) without using [plugins](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130307/linear-referencing-in-qgis) or [PostGIS](http://kartoza.com/en/blog/how-to-create-a-point-distance-marker-layer-along-a-line-in-postgis/) or creating points along the line. I tried working with `line_interpolate_point` (for both `rule based labeling` and the repetition of `single labels`) but I don't think this is the correct direction.

Basically, I want to have a simple labeling style which displays geometry-based values every X m.

Comment: which geometry-based values do you want to label?

Comment: "label the distance along a line every 1000 m e.g." - as in distance from starting point

Answer (score 4):

This is Python solution for the QGIS Python console.

Just paste the code (after renaming "lines" to your line layer name) in the console.

It creates points every 100m along every single line feature in a line layer.
Depending on your data, points are located differently when a new line starts/ends (see the picture below). A solution could be to merge lines depending on IDs, etc..

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys
import os

# silence stdout in QGIS Python console
@contextmanager
def silence_stdout():
    new_target = open(os.devnull, "w")
    old_target, sys.stdout = sys.stdout, new_target
    try:
        yield new_target
    finally:
        sys.stdout = old_target

l_layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('lines')[0]

p_lyr = QgsVectorLayer('Point', 'Points', 'memory')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(p_lyr)
pprov = p_lyr.dataProvider()
pprov.addAttributes([QgsField("sum", QVariant.Int)])

with silence_stdout():
    for elem in l_layer.getFeatures():
        sum = 0
        while elem.geometry().length() > sum:
            sum += 100                                    # here you can change the distance
            geom_point = elem.geometry().interpolate(sum)
            point_feat = QgsFeature()
            point_feat.setGeometry(geom_point)
            point_feat.setAttributes([sum])
            pprov.addFeatures([point_feat])

p_lyr.updateExtents()
p_lyr.triggerRepaint()
p_lyr.updateFields()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but I do know the `points along lines` tool and would prefer not to use it - or similar solutions. The labels should be attached directly to the line layer. If you doubt this is possible, then this is also a valuable insight.

Comment: So a better solution would be to segmentize a the line layer to 100m segments for labeling. I would update my answer regarding this.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "better". It is a possible, feasible solution (and known to me) but not the desired one. Sorry